# How to delete parts of XML data and write it to a new file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, lxml

I have a data structure such as following. The input file is pretty large and thus I am trying to find an efficient method.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<corpus name="corpus">
  <recording audio="audio.wav" name="first audio">
    <segment name="1" start="0" end="2">
        <orth>some text 1</orth>
    </segment>
    <segment name="2" start="2" end="4">
        <orth>some text 2</orth>
    </segment>
    <segment name="3" start="4" end="6">
        <orth>some text 3</orth>
    </segment>
  </recording>
</corpus>
```

given an input file containing number of files such as

```
1
3
```

it would remove the segments that has those `name`. For example, 1 and 3 was given so segments with names 1 and 3 has been removed.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<corpus name="corpus">
  <recording audio="audio.wav" name="first audio">
    <segment name="2" start="2" end="4">
        <orth>some text 2</orth>
    </segment>
  </recording>
</corpus>
```

the code I have so far

```
from lxml import etree

with open("g.xml", "r") as xml_file:
    xml_data = xml_file.read()

with open('del_names.txt', 'r') as file:
    list_of_names = file.read().split("\n")

new_xml = xml_data
for each_name in list_of_names:
    print(each_name)
    tree = etree.XML(new_xml.encode())
    find_segments = tree.xpath("*//segment[@name='{}']".format(each_name))
    for each_segment in find_segments:
        each_segment.getparent().remove(each_segment)
    new_xml = str(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True), encoding="utf-8")

print(new_xml)
```

The problem with the code is that, I ran the code for 2 hours now and it didn't even output a single line. I am not sure what efficient way I could do this.

How do I accomplish this? I also think having 2 might be unnecessary is that correct?

Comment: "having 2" - do you mean "having 2 loops"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code takes longer than expected, you can always start with some print statements to get a better idea were time is spent.

For your task a single loop should suffice. Iterate over all 'segment' elements in the xml file. When a segment's name is included in the del_names.txt file, delete it.

To make lookup for names faster, I convert the list of names to a `set`.

```py
from lxml import etree

with open("g.xml", "r") as xml_file:
    xml_data = xml_file.read()
print("read xml data")

with open('del_names.txt', 'r') as file:
    names_to_delete = set(file.read().split("\n"))
print("read text data")

new_xml = xml_data
tree = etree.XML(new_xml.encode())

for segment in tree.xpath("*//segment"):
    name = segment.attrib.get("name")
    if name in names_to_delete:
        print(f"will delete segment '{name}'")
        segment.getparent().remove(segment)

print(" result ".center(80, "="))

new_xml = str(etree.tostring(tree, encoding="unicode", pretty_print=True))
print(new_xml)
```

**Output:**

```
read xml data
read text data
will delete segment '1'
will delete segment '3'
==================================== result ====================================
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<corpus name="corpus">
    <recording audio="audio.wav" name="first audio">
        <segment name="2" start="2" end="4">
            <orth>some text 2</orth>
        </segment>
    </recording>
</corpus>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works perfectly, except some utf8 problems. For example, ```dáár``` turns into ```d&#225;&#225;r```. How should I fix this?

Comment: Please try my updated answer. `new_xml = str(etree.tostring(tree, encoding="unicode", pretty_print=True))` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_string = """ <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<corpus name="corpus">
  <recording audio="audio.wav" name="first audio">
    <segment name="1" start="0" end="2">
        <orth>some text 1</orth>
    </segment>
    <segment name="2" start="2" end="4">
        <orth>some text 2</orth>
    </segment>
    <segment name="3" start="4" end="6">
        <orth>some text 3</orth>
    </segment>
  </recording>
</corpus> """

soup = BeautifulSoup(my_string, 'html.parser')
ids = [1,3] #IDs to delete

for id in ids:
    elements = soup.find_all("segment", attrs = {"name": str(id)})
    for element in elements:
        element.decompose()
    
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: If the answer helped you in some way please consider giving it +1! :)